# Scroll image upto div content without position: sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have the image to scroll up and down within div.
Position sticky works when using chrome but not on IE, Edge, or firefox.

html

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="stamp-img" class="col-md-6">
             <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css

```
#stamp-img {
    position: sticky;
    top: 35%;

    img {
        margin: 50px 0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use fixed? Sticky has cross browser compatibility issues as stated in the other answer.

```css
#stamp-img {
  /* changed to fixed */
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  /* new */
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  /* end new */
  img {
    margin: 50px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="stamp-img" class="col-md-6">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x500">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: tried using fixed.  The problem I ran was that instead of that div container it will scroll from top to bottom of the whole content.

Comment: Is this helpful though? becuase it should work fine as per the example above otherwise if you can provide a broader scenario I can try to help you from there.

Comment: Yeah helps me or right path.  So I used col-md-6 so there is image on left and descriptions on the right side.  Need to figure how to align this properly since fixed will make image be on-front of description. Also seems like fixed is applied to the body of the html instead of just the parent wrapping section.

Comment: Yes fixed will make it stick always in the same place when you scroll your content, you don't want that? You could try either absolute or relative if not.

Comment: Yeah so the code I provide was one of proportion.  So the problem is image will follow all the way from top and bottom of full content.  I am just trying to have image scroll on the above code content only.  Absolute might be the solution.

Comment: Ok, if you need any further help let me know, hope this helps though. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

"the sticky property is an experimental API that should not be used in production code"

=> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position